# Why is this string equality test failing?

Tags: bash, shell

Good day

I am writing a simple script to test if a site is up after the war file has been deployed by Gitlab.

The Bash script thus far is:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
    do
        response=$(curl -Is http://mysite/ | head -n 1)
        echo "$response"
        if [ "$response" == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]; then
            echo "SITE UP"
            $i = 11
        fi
        sleep 5s
    done
if [ $i == 11 ]; then
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

The lines `echo "$response"` and `echo "SITE UP"` is only there for troubleshooting and will be removed from the final script.

My output in the terminal at this point is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Clearly the string comparison is failing. Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The HTTP headers use CRLF line-endings (`\r\n`):

```
$ curl -Is http://example.com | head -n1 | od -c
0000000   H   T   T   P   /   1   .   1       2   0   0       O   K  \r
0000020  \n
0000021
```

But command substitution only strips the trailing newline (`\n`), and not the carriage return (`\r`), so there's an extra character:

```
$ response=$(curl -Is http://example.com/ | head -n 1)
$ printf "$response" | od -c
0000000   H   T   T   P   /   1   .   1       2   0   0       O   K  \r
0000020
$ printf "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" | od -c
0000000   H   T   T   P   /   1   .   1       2   0   0       O   K
0000017
```

You can try deleting the carriage return:

```
response=$(curl -Is http://mysite/ | head -n 1 | tr -d '\r')
```

Then:

```
$ response=$(curl -Is http://example.com/ | head -n 1 | tr -d '\r')
$ printf "$response" | od -c
0000000   H   T   T   P   /   1   .   1       2   0   0       O   K
0000017
```

Comment: Excellent answer thanks, the equality check now works 100% The rest of the script not that well yet :)

Answer (score 1):

The `if` command actually takes a command as an argument, and evaluates its return value. The command in `if [ ... ]` is `[`, which is an alias for [`test`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html).

And if you read [the `test` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) you will see that to compare strings you use single `=`. So you should instead have

```
if [ "$response" = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]; then
```

Note that leading and trailing spaces in `$response` could lead to the strings being unequal. Examples of spaces include newline `"\n"` or carriage-return `"\r"`.